# Cannot find the declaration of element 'ScrollView'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have the following error in Android Studio, and i really do not know what i am doing wrong:

[image]

I tried to make a clean project, but it did not resolve the problem.

here you have my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cityguidetour"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


}
```

Any help please ?

Comment: can you post an image of your build.gradle (app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to delete the project and create a new one in Android Studio to overcome this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Once Try

```
Build-> Clean Project
Build -> Rebuild project
Build -> Clean Project
and restart android studio with File -> invalidate cache /Restart
```

Comment: check SDK : Android SDK platform-Tools, Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Build-Tools, Whether it is outdated or not